# Specific Lines after first occurrence of keyword

Tags: vbscript

I have a file in which I am able to find the keyword using vbscript but further I need to keep copying next 3-4 lines down it, until I find another occurrence of similar pattern of keyword.
I have written something like this - ( I am newbee for assume I am dumb )

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set inFile  = fso.OpenTextFile("FileName", 1)
Set outFile = fso.OpenTextFile("FileName", 8, True)
outFile.WriteLine("This is some sample data.")
strAnswer = InputBox("Please enter a value:", _
    "Enter Value")
Do until inFile.AtEndOfStream
  line = inFile.ReadLine
  If InStr(line, strAnswer) Then
    outFile.WriteLine line ' Copy the line and write to output file
    serNum = Left(line, 7)
    'If Not ((line = inFile.ReadLine())
    'take first 3 char and find the next occurance of it
    'copy all lines until that line
    WScript.Echo "Found"
  End If        
Loop
outfile.Close
Set fSO = Nothing
```

Any suggestion is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sub-loop to continue writing until the serial number is found again.

```
Do until inFile.AtEndOfStream
    line = inFile.ReadLine
    If InStr(line, strAnswer) Then
        outFile.WriteLine line ' Copy the line and write to output file
        serNum = Left(line, 7)

        ' Continue writing until EOF or serial number is found...
        Do While Not inFile.AtEndOfStream
            line = inFile.ReadLine
            If InStr(line, serNum) = 0 Then outFile.WriteLine line
        Loop

    End If        
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the state of the variable `serNum` to decide what you need to do with the current line:

```vbs
Do until inFile.AtEndOfStream
  line = inFile.ReadLine

  If Not IsEmpty(serNum) And InStr(line, serNum) > 0 Then WScript.Quit
  If IsEmpty(serNum) And InStr(line, strAnswer) > 0 Then serNum = Left(line, 7)
  If Not IsEmpty(serNum) Then outFile.WriteLine line
Loop
```

- The first condition checks if you have found the second match and then quits.
- The second condition checks if you have found the first match and then initializes `serNum`.
- The third condition causes all lines from the first match to the line before the second match to be written to the output file.